# Recovering phase of harmonics in an arbitrary pulse train

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, phase, zero-padding

I want to recover the phase of the harmonic components of a pulse train.

There's a lot of cool resources out there that talk about recovering power spectra from signals in several ideal and non-ideal situations. I'm struggling however to find any detailed work on phase recovery. The only resource I have to off of is this blog post which seems to suggest zero padding signals `(http://gaidi.ca/weblog/does-zero-padding-a-fft-matter)`. To this end, I started doing some experiments which I've listed here!

**TLDR**: Please point me to good books or links about recovering accurate phase from signals.

**TLDR Experiment results**: Windowing is good, zero padding is very bad

## My experiments

I created a pulse shape of 100 time samples which can be repeated every one second

```
def pulse_shape(center, width):
    return lambda x: np.exp(-(center - x)**2 / width) \
        + 0.5*np.exp(-(center-0.1 - x)**4 / width)

def get_one_cycle(samples_per_cycle):
    t = np.arange(samples_per_cycle) / samples_per_cycle
    y = np.zeros_like(t)
    y += pulse_shape(center=0, width=0.01)(t)
    y += pulse_shape(center=1, width=0.01)(t)
    return y
```

A cycle looks like this:
[image: one peak-to-peak cycle of the pulse train]
And 5 cycles looks like this:
[image: five peak-to-peak cycles of the pulse train]

Since this signal is 1 Hz, we would expext to see peaks in the power spectrum at multiples of 1 Hz (the harmonics). Deriving the PSD in the python code:

```
    SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE = 100
    total_num_samples = num_cycles * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE
    y = np.zeros(total_num_samples)

    for i in range(num_cycles):
        start_idx = i * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE
        end_idx = start_idx + SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE
        y[start_idx : end_idx] = get_one_cycle(SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)

    dft = np.fft.rfft(y)
    freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(total_num_samples, d=1/SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)
    psd = np.abs(dft)**2
    psd = psd / np.max(psd)
```

And plotting the power spectrum (done here 8 times with between 1 and 8 cycles of the signal):
[image: The power spectrum of the cycle with different numbers of cycles]
Sure enough, the power spectrum shows a consistent value for the power at each harmonic no matter how many cycles we put in the pulse train.
But what we're really interested in for this post is the phase. Plotting the phase spectrum analagously to the power:

```
    phase = np.arctan2(np.imag(dft), np.real(dft))
```

[image: The phase spectrum of the cycle with different numbers of cycles]
Once again, the values outside of the harmonics aren't really important and their values are likely driven by float errors. What's important is that no matter how many pulses we put in our pulse train, the phase at each harmonic remains the same.

## Non-integer number of pulses

What if we don't in fact have an integer number of cycles in our pulse train though? What if we have a pulse train that has, say, 5.1 pulses in it?
[image: A pulse train with 5.1 pulses in it]
Note that if we were to repeat this graph, there would be a discontinuous jump every 5.1 seconds. You would expect to see this affecting the frequency domain (after all, the DFT by design assumes that the signal loops continuously across the edges).

So what happens if we want to recover the phase at 1Hz, 2Hz, 3Hz, etc?

```
    SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE = 100
    total_num_samples = int(num_cycles * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)
    y = np.zeros(total_num_samples)

    for i in range(int(num_cycles)):
        start_idx = i * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE
        end_idx = start_idx + SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE
        y[start_idx : end_idx] = get_one_cycle(SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)
    num_extra_samples = int(num_cycles * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE) \
        - int(int(num_cycles) * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)
    if num_extra_samples > 0:
        y[end_idx:] = get_one_cycle(SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)[:num_extra_samples]

    dft = np.fft.rfft(y)
    freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(total_num_samples, d=1/SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)

    phase = np.arctan2(np.imag(dft), np.real(dft))
```

plotting this for 1.1 cycles, 2.1 cycles, 3.1 cycles, etc.
[image: Phase spectrum of different numbers of non-integer cycles (0.1 extra)]
And similarly for 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, etc.
[image: Phase spectrum of different numbers of non-integer cycles (0.5 extra)]
We can see that as we increase the number of cycles, the phase gets closer and closer to converging on the true phase. But the convergence doesn't look particularly fast - This is especially visible in the 4th harmonic which is struggling to match the correct value even with 8.5 pulses.

So how can we get an accurate phase with as little pulses as possible?

### Experiment 1: Apply a hann window

Peforming a DFT? Use a window. At least, that's the advice I always seemed to have been given, though I've never heard much chatter about it in the context of phase. Let's try it! The code is the same as last time but with `y = y*hann(len(y))`.
The plots look like this:

```
Link to image until I have enough reputation to embed more:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjKUO.png
Caption: phase spectrum of a pulse train with non-integer pulses, after appling hann window
```

Sure enough, this seems to be a nice improvment. This is especially nice in the case that you don't necessarily know the number of pulses in your pulse train beforehand.

### Experiment 2: zero-padding to the next full cycle

For this experiment, we pad with zeros up to the next length that would be an exact number of cycles.
For example, at 100 time samples per cycle, 8.5 cycles = 850 samples. We pad with an extra 50 zeros at the end to get a total of 900 samples or '9 cycles'. Code:

```
    SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE = 100
    total_num_samples_padded = (int(num_cycles) + 1) * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE
    y = np.zeros(total_num_samples_padded)
    t = np.arange(total_num_samples_padded) / SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE

    for i in range(int(num_cycles)):
        start_idx = i * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE
        end_idx = start_idx + SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE
        y[start_idx : end_idx] = get_one_cycle(SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)

    num_extra_samples = int(num_cycles * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE) \
                         - int(int(num_cycles) * SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)
    if num_extra_samples > 0:
        y[end_idx:end_idx + num_extra_samples] = get_one_cycle(SAMPLES_PER_CYCLE)[:num_extra_samples]
```

And plots:

```
Link to image until I have enough reputation to embed more:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADQDn.png
Caption: phase spectrum after padding to the next integer number of cycles
```

This surprised me. After hearing about how zero-padding can perform mirracles in signal processing, I expected the zero padding approach to at least improve from the non-padded signal. But it's actually worse (see the end for a full comparison of methods)

### Experiment 3: zero-padding up to 10x the signal length

Last experiment tried a small amount of padding. Let's try a lot! each time, the signal is padded to 10x the length such that the first 10% is the actual signal and the last 90% is zeros.
The plot looks like this:

```
Link to image until I have enough reputation to embed more:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ2v9.png
Caption: phase spectrum after 10x padding with a zero-mean signal
```

It's definitely different, but the convergence isn't anything incredible. So far Hann still seems to beat it. This analysis is definitely making me lose faith in the 'miracle' of zero padding.

### Experiment 4: subtract the mean, zero-padding up to 10x the signal length.

Maybe the issue is that the mean of this signal is not zero? I should perhaps not be padding with zeros, but in fact with the mean of the signal (alternatively, as I've done here, I can subtract the mean of the signal and still pad with zeros).
Code is same as last time except with `y[:signal_length] -= np.mean(y[:signal_length])`
Plot:

```
Link to image until I have enough reputation to embed more:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxrS2.png
Caption: phase spectrum after 10x padding with a zero-mean signal
```

Again, potentially better for the 1st and 3rd harmonics, but still poorer than doing nothing.

### Experiment 5: subtract the mean, hann, zero-padding up to 10x the signal length.

Final experiment throws everything together. Hann window (just on the signal portion), zero mean signal, 10x paddding. Let's see what happens:

```
Link to image until I have enough reputation to embed more:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhKXS.png
Caption: phase spectrum after hann windowing, 10x padding with a zero-mean signal
```

Definitely better than last time. It seems like the true work is being done by the hann window though, not the zero padding.

## Final results

To summarise my experiments, I plotted the error against number of cycles at each harmonic. This was plotted for the normal un-edited unpadded signal as well as the 5 experiments listed above. These were the results.
[image: Phase error plots as a function of number of cycles in the pulse train for four harmonics.]
It seems that hann was the winner the whole time. To my surprise, it also seems like zero padding is actually a terrible idea, and actually worse than not doing any padding. I don't know how universal these conclusions are and would love to see some more detailed and general work on phase errors.

There's an awful lot out there about the accuracy of power spectra but phase seems very difficult to find. If anyone has any useful links that can shed more light on minimising phase error, I'd love to find out more. Thanks so much!

Comment: this is more of a general remark: Don't fall prey to any conclusion made through linear interpolation of points, e.g. of samples in time or coefficients of a DFT. Because there's no linear interpolation between these; if there is a sensible interpolation, it's a sinc-interpolation. There's no sharp angled peaks in the analog signal a sampled signal like this would be representative of!

Comment: @MarcusMüller ah yes, that's a very good point. I think It doesn't make a whole lot of differerence in this post as the majority of experiments have datapoints at or very near to the harmonics. But it's definitely a good point and good to keep in mind. That will likely affect the lower resolution spectra